# cv2.imread always returns None type - using cv virtual environment

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I am using a virtual environment, which I called cv. I am trying to read into a numpy array using opencv a .cr2 raw image.

Using:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("raw.cr2")
print img
```

Returns:

```
None
```

Always.

I believe the problem is in the path of `raw.cr2`, which cannot be found apparently. I have tried including the absolute path in the file I pass to imread. My file is in the home folder (~) where I run python from. I know the path is the issue because if I run `sys.os.exists(path)`, it always returns `False`.

Lastly, I also tried reading `raw.cr2` using scipy.misc:

```
img = scipy.misc.imread(path)
```

Returns:

```
IOError: cannot identify image file 'raw.cr2'
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the path instead of using `~`?

Comment: @EdSmith Yes, I have! Still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you ever solved this. I recently encountered the same problem (using ArchLinux) and found it was a permissions issue. Had to chown the images I wanted to use. Silly me.